# Trouble viewing Google Map page in iFrame in Windows phone 8

Tags: google-maps, iframe, windows-phone-8, cordova

I'm building Windows Phone 8 Application, I have map page included in iframe.
when running the App it shows error message

[image]

```
We're having trouble displaying this page 
Try refesh this page.
```

Also I try to remove the script from the page and still getting the error message.
Also I don't have webbrowser control, because I don't need it.

Comment: Any help will be appreciate :)